# CSS selector for a class in an id

Tags: css, css-selectors

Whats wrong with this Selector?

```
#dialogEditPage .ui-dialog-titlebar
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this selector. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Nothing........ it might just not select anything in your HTML because you don't have these elements. Let me have a look at it... oh, you did not post your HTML. Would be wise to do so.

Comment: or you should select PeeHaa's answer as correct and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with it.

Check out what CSS rules are applied with Firebug for FireFox or with Chrome or the IE toolbar.